# Syntax error on python

Tags: python, printing, syntax

I'm trying to do a simple function to delete some cache files.
But I'm getting an syntax error, and I dont know why...

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import filecmp
import urllib
import shutil

def clean ():
    shutil.rmtree('/apks')
    os.remove('apk_cache')
    os.remove('info.xml')
    os.makedirs('apks')
    print "Cache - Clear"

    return menu ()
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Joao Carreira\ownCloud\Development\Python\Aptoide_Utils\utils.p
", line 14
   print "Cache - Clear"
                       ^
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Python 3.x, you should write it as follow:

```
print("Cache - Clear")
```

`print` is a function in Python 3.x.

---

```
>>> print "Cache - Clear"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Cache - Clear"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("Cache - Clear")
Cache - Clear
>>> print
<built-in function print>
```